# Saving Keras model fails after renaming layers

Tags: keras

I have a problem with renaming layers. Below is the simplest example illustrating the problem:

```python
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Input
from keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(784,))

x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

# This creates a model that includes
# the Input layer and three Dense layers
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

for i, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    layer.name = 'layer' + str(i)

print(model.summary())

model.save('temp')
```

It fails with the message:

```python
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/save_load.py", line 24, in <module>
    model.save('temp')
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2416, in save
    save_model(self, filepath, overwrite)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 101, in save_model
    'config': model.get_config()
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2281, in get_config
    new_node_index = node_conversion_map[node_key]
    KeyError: 'layer0_ib-0'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I know I can pass names to the layer constructor, it seems not to fail in this case, but is there any chance to improve my solution?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this error. Could you give me the versions of your libraries and your os?

Comment: This is an extract from pip freeze : Keras==2.0.0
numpy==1.14.1
tensorboard==1.6.0
tensorflow==1.5.0
tensorflow-tensorboard==1.5.1 . And the os is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Comment: I have the same problem, the model performance changes when renaming the layers. How did you solve this problem?@kmichael08

Comment: As far as I remember changing Keras version worked, although this approach doesn't seem to be supported and reliable, so I've dropped layers renaming. Unfortunately I'm not sure about the exact version, try Keras 2.1.5